# Browser is not loading pages fully

Tags: 13.10, browser

So I am using Chromium and Nightly broswers. As of yesterday, I am suddenly unable to visit a lot of pages. I just open the page, facebook for example. It loads almost everything and after that the whole page becomes unclickable. Only way to open it again is to close the tab and re-type the address.

What is wrong here? If any additional info is needed, let me know..

Comment: Can you try clearing your cache and trying again?

Comment: I am able to browse facebook now but when I opened youtube, the same thing happened again, and also some other pages I opened just load for ever when I try to load them.

Comment: Can you check other devices on network, it might be related to your router?